# After switching to the initial screen, one extra screen was left in the stack

Tags: flutter

There is a start screen from which I first go to another screen using the method

```
Navigator.of(context).push(...
```

Further transitions are also carried out through the `push` method.

But then when I want to return to the initial screen I do

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const InitialView(),
          ),
          ModalRoute.withName('/'),
 );
```

and I will be taken back to the initial screen.
BUT
it turns out that if I click on the hardware “back” button again, it will bring the initial screen again...

Why does this happen? It turns out that there is one extra initial screen left in the stack.

Now, if you press "back" again then the application will close.

Why is there one extra screen left on the navigation stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are popping until initial view and pushing it again. Try pop until

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
```